# Select a word before and after a pattern (Hyphen is the pattern ) on shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Select a word before and after a pattern (Hyphen is the pattern) using shell script.

Out is a text file which has hundreds of lines and i have selected the ones which has Required ID's, however i need to select ALPHABETS-NUMBERS. Count of Alphabet and Number varies.

I have tried various utilities including cut, sed, awk, however it s trimming the required fields.

**Input**

```
cat out | grep "[A-Z][-][0-9]"
BUG-KEYWORD-BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
Output is referred in ABC-1043
Please refer DEF-11234
```

**Output Should be**

```
BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
ABC-1043
DEF-11234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+' file
```

The `o` option makes `grep` output matches only, `E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax (no need to escape `+`), and `[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+` matches all substrings that start with one or more letters, then have a `-` char and then have one or more digits.

**Alternatives**

The above solution extracts **all, multiple matches** even if they occur on the same line in the file. If you do not want this behavior, and only want to match the `<letters>-<digits>` *at the end of lines*, you should simply add `$` at the end of the regex pattern and use

```sh
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+$' file`
```

If you need **to extract the last occurrence on each line** that is not necessarily at the end of a line, use a PCRE based regex with GNU `grep` or `pcregrep` (in case you installed it, a common workaround tool with non-GNU `grep` versions):

```sh
grep -oP '^(?:.*\P{L})?\K\p{L}+-\d+' file
pcregrep -o '^(?:.*\P{L})?\K\p{L}+-\d+' file
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QR9ys9/1). In a PCRE pattern, `\p{L}` matches any letter (you may still use `[[:alpha:]]`, too) and `\d` matches any ASCII digit, `^(?:.*\P{L})?\K` matches start of string (`^`), and then an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`) and then any char other than a letter (`\P{L}`), this part makes the engine go to the last match occurrence of `\p{L}+-\d+`.

See the [main solution online demo](https://ideone.com/h0HI2a):

```sh
s='BUG-KEYWORD-BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
Output is referred in ABC-1043
Please refer DEF-11234'
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
ABC-1043
DEF-11234
```

Comment: I was too slow... `grep -o -E '[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+'`

Comment: Thanks a lot and this one is also working fine.

Comment: @Raj Glad it works. Also, I would like to note that `grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+'` solution extracts *all*, multiple matches even if they occur on the same line in the file. If you do not want this, and only want to match the `<letters>-<digits>` at the end of lines, you should simply add `$` at the end of the regex pattern: `grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+-[0-9]+$' file`. If you need to extract the last occurrence that is not necessarily at the end of a line, use `grep -oP '^(.*\P{L})?\K\p{L}+-\d+' file`

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+$/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+$/){      ##using match function to match alphabets dash and digits till last of line.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Printing matches sub string of matched regex.
}
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hehehe.... This is one that `awk` does well, but good old `grep` does a bit more concisely -- but well done.

Answer (score 4):

I like the approach with `grep`, and `awk`, but since you tagged `sed` as well, to round out your answer selection, you can use:

```
sed -E 's/^.*(\b[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+).*$/\1/' file
```

Where `-E` extended regex is selected and then the normal substitution `s/find/replace/` is used where:

- `find` is `^.*(\b[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+).*$` with `^.*` anchoring to the beginning of line, discarding zero or more characters of any type and then capturing the text within the capture group `(...)` and discarding zero or more character to the end of line `.*$`,
- the capture group selects a `\b` word-boundary followed by one or more `A-Za-z` `[:alpha:]` characters, then a `'-'`, followed by one or more `0-9` `[:digits:]`,
- the `replace` simply reinserts what was captured using the first backreference `\1`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, you would have:

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*(\b[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+).*$/\1/' file
BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
ABC-1043
DEF-11234
```

Comment: Thank you. This one took a bit of thought with the boundary selection being key to matching from the beginning of the alpha-characters. (took me a bit to psych that out `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
BUG-KEYWORD-BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
Output is referred in ABC-1043
Please refer DEF-11234
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[A-Z]+-[0-9]+"}{print $1}' file.txt
```

output

```
BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
ABC-1043
DEF-11234
```

Explanation: I inform AWK too look for fields matching pattern, then print first field. Disclaimer: I assume in every line uppercase-digits appears exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

And with GNU `awk` for multi-char RS, RT:

```
awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+' 'RT {print RT}' file
BUG-101
ABC-10
DEF-10327
ABC-1043
DEF-11234
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE ':a;/[[:digit:]]+-[[:alpha:]]+/{s//\n&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;s///;ba}' file
```

This extracts one or more of the desired strings and prints them each on a separate line.

It surrounds the desired string by newlines then removes up to and including the first newline, prints up to and including the newline, removes what it just printed and repeats.

An exotic alternative using the same method:

```
sed -E '/\n/!s/[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/\n&\n/g;/^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/P;D' file
```

N.B. These sed solutions are included for completeness, but as grep offers the most efficient/terse option, I would use that.